# Using broom::glance() in conjunction with glmmTMB

Tags: r, broom

I've run a set of 23 models using glmmTMB. (I've set up my models as a `list`, example code seen below)

```
cand.models<-list()
cand.models[[1]]<-glmmTMB(count~depth + slope + SST + (1|individual), family=list(family="truncated_nbinom1", link="log"), data=df)
cand.models[[2]]<-glmmTMB(count~depth + slope + (1|individual), family=list(family="truncated_nbinom1", link="log"), data=df)
```

I would like to create a summary table that provides the deviance for each model contained within `cand.models`. I tried using `broom::glance()`, which is supposed to create a "one row" summary that includes deviance, among other things like AIC and BIC.

```
summ.table<-do.call(rbind, lapply(cand.models, broom::glance))
```

However, the output does not include the model deviance! (it only includes sigma, logLik, AIC, BIC, and df.residual). Does anyone know why it is not providing the deviance (an issue specific to glmmTMB, perhaps?). Or, does anyone have an alternate solution for extracting the deviance?

Comment: When I generated one of the example models in the help for `glmmTMB` and tried `glance` on it I received the following error: `glance doesn't know how to deal with data of class glmmTMB`. I tried this with both the latest CRAN release and the development version of `broom`, so I'm wondering how you were even able to get `glance` to work on a `glmmTMB` model. When I run `glance` on model objects returned by `lm`, `glm`, and `lmer` (from the `lme4` package), `glance` *does* include the deviance in the output.

Comment: Interesting. I downloaded  devtools::install_github("bbolker/broom") so that I could use `dotwhisker::dwplot()` with `glmmTMB`. Maybe that changed how `broom` interacts with `glmmTMB` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on the comments: The ["master" version of `broom`](https://github.com/tidyverse/broom) doesn't include a `glance` method for `glmmTMB` models, meaning `glance` doesn't work for `glmmTMB` models.

The version of `broom` you're using is a [forked](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) version by [Ben Bolker (bbolker)](https://github.com/bbolker/broom) to which he added a new `glance` method that works for `glmmTMB` model objects. However, this `glance` method doesn't include the `deviance` in the output. Nevertheless, since `deviance = -2*log(likelihood)`, you can do the following:

```
summ.table$deviance = -2 * summ.table$logLik
```

Comment: note: (1) there is now a [broom.mixed package](https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed) under development that does this. (2) you need to be careful about the definition of the deviance, i.e. is it -2*log(L) or -2*log(L/L_0) ?

Comment: I have installed bbolker version and it says: Error: No glance method for objects of class summary.glmmTMB